# php5 : feed column from one query into another query and display output

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to write PHP code where I connect to two different databases.

On the first database I run a query and get a column (for e.g. column output: 1,2,3,4,5), now I need to feed 1,2,3,4,5 into a second SQL query which has a statement like:

```
select key from table where foo = '1','2','3','4','5'
```

How it can be done in PHP?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're looking for the [MySQL IN Clause](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm)

That doesn't really have to anything with PHP, or I don't really get what you mean. Anyway:

```
$query1 = $db->query("SELECT values FROM table");
$results = $db->fetchResults();

$query2 = $db2->query("SELECT x FROM foo WHERE y IN (".implode(',', $results).")");
$results = $db2->fetchResults();
```

Those lines of pseudo code (without validation) should get you started.

Comment: Forgot to apply proper escaping in your `implode` :)

Answer (score 1):

Using just SQL codes, you can do this

```
SELECT * FROM `table_1` WHERE `foo` IN (SELECT `bar` from `table_2`)
```

Comment: The OP really should be aware, this is the more concise and more efficient answer.